# Android - Are the speaker and mute status a property of a single call or the device itself

Tags: android

I wanted to know if when you turn on/off the speaker during a call, do you actually set a property of the call itself or a property of the device and its system?

Same question when muting/unmuting a call.

Will it be more accurate to do something like:

`callObject.muteCall();` or `MuteStatus.muteDevice();`

Comment: since 3 hours have passed already - did you maybe try it yourself? if yes, could you post your answer? :-)

Comment: I got an API which is already taking care of it and I need to use it in a GUI. but the API doesn't tell me if it's a part of a call or a part of the device so I just want to build it correctly. If you want to know how to do it then you got the AudioManager to turn the speaker on and off.